# Exporting to Excel from c# and adding in another column with Excel formula

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

I am trying to export the contents of my `DataGridView` Into `Excel`, I have the code to do this however what I want is for it to add an additional column in with an `Excel Formula`

I have this code so far

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
        app.Visible = true;
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        worksheet.Name = "Testing this";
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        workbook.SaveAs("c:\\output.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        app.Quit();
    }
```

I am unsure as to go about adding in the formula column, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `.Formula` property of the range you want to add the formula, but if you are referencing other cells (which is probable), then the `.FormulaR1C1` is really nice because it lets you reference cells based on their relative position rather than trying to figure out what the Row/Column is.

In your example above, this would add a formula as the very last column and take the value of the second column from the left and multiply it by two:

```
int formulaCol = dataGridView2.Columns.Count + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }

    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, formulaCol].FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-2]*2";
}
```

`R[0]` means the current row.  `R1` would be one row ahead, and `R[-1]` would be one row back.

-- EDIT 11/28/17 --

Per your comment, this is a neat trick to convert a standard formula to R1C1 without any brain-power.  Type your formula in, as-is.  The go to File->Options->Formulas and check the tab that says "R1C1 Formulas."  It will convert your normal formula to R1C1 and facilitate the use of this in your code.

What's cool is when you copy/paste the formula, you'll notice it doesn't change like the normal A1 style does.

So, in your example, if I put your formula into J7, it would become:

=IF(ISNA(MATCH(R[-5]C[-9],C[-7],0)),"",INDEX(C[-7],MATCH(R[-5]C[-9],C[-7],0)))

This is not right, of course, as it completely depends on which cell you initially enter your standard formula.

So enter it like you normally would, change to R1C1, and use that for your C# code.

[image]

Comment: This is great thank you! I am now struggling a bit to add in my formula, the formula i want to add in is
    =IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,C:C,0)),"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A2,C:C,0))) - Replacing 'A2' with the current 'A' position

Comment: @DavidWaldron -- I edited my answer a bit to help you with this last part.  Try it out, and if you're still having issues, maybe upload a copy of the workbook to dropbox or G-drive

Comment: Perfect exactly what i need! - much easier when you can do the RC conversions automatically